# Typescript string literal from children in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I would like to have the literal type from a prop passed as children to a component. Maybe not possible? I my example i would be happy to have the `Name` type in the `Parent` component.

```
import React from 'react';

interface ChildProps {
    name: string;
}

const Child: React.FC<ChildProps> = () => {
    return 'not important';
};

interface ParentProps {
    children: React.ReactElement<ChildProps>[];
}

const Parent: React.FC<ParentProps> = () => {
    type Name = React.ComponentProps<(typeof children)[number]>; // This is not working but I would like to limit this type to 'a' | 'b'

    return 'not important';
};

const Demo: React.FC = () => {
    return (
        <Parent>
            <Child name="a" />
            <Child name="b" />
        </Parent>
    );
};
```